# Checkbox are not changing their status with MobX

Tags: flutter, mobx

I'm using MobX on Flutter to control states.
Clicking on the FloatingActionButton generates a `ListView` that contains `CheckboxListTile`.
However checkboxes are not changing their status

Could you help me fix this problem?

Below is the code and an image:

**home_controller.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mobx/mobx.dart';
import 'package:flutter_modular/flutter_modular.dart';

part 'home_controller.g.dart';

@Injectable()
class HomeController = _HomeControllerBase with _$HomeController;

abstract class _HomeControllerBase with Store {
  @observable
  ObservableList<CheckBoxModel> mapValues = <CheckBoxModel>[].asObservable();

  @observable
  ListView listViewCheckbox;

  @action
  void listViewChekbox(value) {
    for (var i in value) {
      mapValues.add(CheckBoxModel(key: i));
    }
  }
}

class CheckBoxModel{
  
  CheckBoxModel({this.key, this.checked = false});
  
  String key;
  bool checked;
}
```

**home_page.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mobx/flutter_mobx.dart';
import 'package:flutter_modular/flutter_modular.dart';
import 'home_controller.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  const HomePage({Key key, this.title = "Home"}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends ModularState<HomePage, HomeController> {
  HomeController controller = HomeController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Observer(builder: (_) {
        return controller.mapValues == null ? Container() : ListView.builder(
          itemCount: controller.mapValues.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, int index){
            return CheckboxListTile(
              title: Text(controller.mapValues[index].key),
              value: controller.mapValues[index].checked,
              onChanged: (bool value) {
                controller.mapValues[index].checked = value;
              },
            );
          },
        );
      }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          List listValues = ['foo', 'bar'];
          controller.listViewChekbox(listValues);
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

According to the image, the `ListView` of `CheckboxListTile` is created but the checkboxes do not change their status.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution found was to insert `setState`

```
onChanged: (bool value) {
    setState(() {
        controller.mapValues[index].checked = value;
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `setState()` or anything else mobX does that for you, you just need to edit you abstract class to tell mobX main variable value changed, like next

```dart
abstract class _HomeControllerBase with Store {
  @observable
  ObservableList<CheckBoxModel> mapValues = <CheckBoxModel>[].asObservable();

  @observable
  ListView listViewCheckbox;

  @action
  void listViewChekbox(value) {
    for (var i in value) {
      mapValues.add(CheckBoxModel(key: i));
    }
    mapValues = mapValues;
  }
}
```

That's how you can solve it.